# Textfield limit the number of lines using multiline keyboardType

Tags: flutter

Using a Textfield with keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline does not limit the maximum number of lines that the user can enter.

```
new TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
    maxLines: 4,  
    maxLength: 30,
)
```

With this example the user can add 30 line breaks for example,there's some way to limit the number of lines entered by the user using a TextField property?

I can parse the text later with my own methods, but my question is about to find if there's any TextField property that can help with that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So it feels like an issue. You can find it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15388).

Setting `maxLines` to a value rather than `null` start with an expanded `TextField` with the line number equals to `maxLines` value but then, you can enter as many lines you like.

So just to give you a working workaround I can suggest you to use a [`TextController`](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes).

```
  final _myController = TextEditingController();
  var _textFieldCorrectValue = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _myController.addListener(_chekNumberOfLines);
    super.initState();
  }

 @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

And use it on your TextField

```
TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      maxLines: 4,
      maxLength: 30,
      controller: _myController,
    ),
```

And here the check function:

```
void _chekNumberOfLines() {
    var _lines = _myController.text.split('\n');
    if (_lines.length > 4) {
      _myController.text = _textFieldCorrectValue;
    } else {
      _textFieldCorrectValue = _myController.text;
      var cursorPos = _myController.selection;
      // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11416
      // workaround for cursor position
      cursorPos = new TextSelection.fromPosition(new TextPosition(offset: _myController.text.length));
      _myController.selection = cursorPos;
    }
  }
```

The workaround for the [cursor position](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11416) is a bit tricky 'cause then you cannot change your cursor position. But my goal was to show you also this issue and a quick answer. Use it if you like or comment it otherwise. And don't hesitate to improve my code of course if you found a better way!